# Import Jama library in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to use the Jama Library in my Android Application. But although I have import the jar of Jama in my project I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Jama.Matrix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a new folder called `libs` and put the .jar file there...

Comment: Where should we create the `libs` folder, can you provide more explanation?